# Data not shown from the array of String and Int on a Textview in android

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite

I am fetching the two column data from the database into the `String Array` and the `Int Array`. And i try to show the data over the Text view. But it is not shown and given some errors. The data coming in the arrays but not shown.

My code is below

```
     try
        {
            mydatabase=this.openOrCreateDatabase("testdata", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

            Cursor c=mydatabase.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT name,MAX(user_score) AS max_score  FROM "+TableName+" WHERE user_score IS NOT NULL GROUP BY name  ORDER BY max_score DESC LIMIT 3" , null);
            int column1=c.getColumnIndex("name");
            int column2=c.getColumnIndex("max_score");
            c.moveToFirst();
            if(c!=null)
            {   int i=0;
                do
                //for(int i=0;c.moveToNext();i++)
                {
                    String Name=c.getString(column1);
                    int Score=c.getInt(column2);
                    Data[i]=Name;
                    Data1[i]=Score;
                    /*Data[1]=Name;
                    Data1[1]=Score;*/

                    System.out.println("i:"+i+"Data[i]:"+Data[i]+"Data1[i]:"+Data1[i]);

                    System.out.println("name"+Name+" score"+Score);
                    i++;
                }while(c.moveToNext());
                TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
                TextView points=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.points);
                TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
                TextView points1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.points1);
                tv.setText(Data[0]);
                points.setText(Data1[0]);
                tv1.setText(Data[1]);
                points1.setText(Data1[1]);
                setContentView(main);
}
```

My Logcat is:

```
 06-04 13:40:35.761: E/ERROR(1347): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x9a
06-04 13:40:35.761: E/ERROR(1347):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
06-04 13:40:35.761: E/ERROR(1347):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2817)
06-04 13:40:35.761: E/ERROR(1347):  at com.k_trivia_cricket.com.high_score.onCreate(high_score.java:76)
06-04 13:40:35.761: E/ERROR(1347):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-04 13:40:35.761: E/ERROR(1347):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-04 13:40:35.761: E/ERROR(1347):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-04 13:40:35.761: E/ERROR(1347):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-04 13:40:35.761: E/ERROR(1347):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-04 13:40:35.761: E/ERROR(1347):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-04 13:40:35.761: E/ERROR(1347):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-04 13:40:35.761: E/ERROR(1347):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-04 13:40:35.761: E/ERROR(1347):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 13:40:35.761: E/ERROR(1347):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-04 13:40:35.761: E/ERROR(1347):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-04 13:40:35.761: E/ERROR(1347):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-04 13:40:35.761: E/ERROR(1347):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: tv.setText(Data[0]+""); pass as a string not res id...

Comment: setContentView(main); line placed at the last, which should be placed immediate  after the super.onCreate() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reasons :

you are passing the int as this function get called [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29)

you need to pass string so show that...
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Answer :

**so as i said in comment points.setText(Data1[0]+""); pass as a string not res id...**

Answer (score 1):

According to your error log,

TextView resource not found "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException".
for solving it please check fallowing,
1-: Have you mention id for that textview in xml file.
2-: May be possible same id for more then one resource.

I hope its help full to you.